# How to replace white space between 2 strings using sed

Tags: sed, replace

How I can replace a single white space for underscore just between 2 strings like the example below, using sed:

```
xxx ccc vvv bbb        333  444  555
   ^   ^   ^   ^^^^^^^^   ^^   ^^   <--- spaces visualized for easier counting
```

Desired output:

```
xxx_ccc_vvv_bbb        333  444  555
```

Answer (score 3):

That's easy, you just do a global (`g`) replace (`s`) of single whitespace characters (`\s`) surrounded by word boundaries (`\b`) with underscores (`_`):

```
sed 's/\b\s\b/_/g'
```

Your example could be run like this:

```
echo "xxx ccc vvv bbb        333  444  555" | sed 's/\b\s\b/_/g'
```

which produces the output you want:

```
xxx_ccc_vvv_bbb        333  444  555
```